# What is this wire out of an smps transformer?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

[image]

I have a PSU that has the same transformer. so what is that wire for?

edit: looking at PCB traces it seems to be connected to the pin of the heat sink
could it be for thermal purposes?

Comment: Any markings on it?

Comment: Check with ohmmeter to all the bottom pins to see if is connected. If not, it is likely a shield between line-side and secondary-side.

Comment: @Steve nope, it's just like the one in the photo. check the edit please.

Comment: @glen_geek it's connected to the heat sink pin

Comment: Looks like a low resistance drain wire for the copper shield.